# Can I get the time of compilation of a java class from withing itself?

Tags: java, compilation

I'd like to print the time of compilation of a class.

```
class Test {
  public Test() {
    System.out.println("Compiled:" + getCompilationTimestamp());
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I just only give glance to this question because jon skeet annswered of this question :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [class file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html), I don't believe that information is stored anywhere - so the answer would be "no".

If you're building your classes into a jar file, you might want to include a metadata file which specifies this information. (I don't *think* there's anything suitable in the [manifest file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JARManifest), but I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Any file has a last-modified timestamp: File.lastModified(); For a compiled File i see no practical scenario where this is not equal to the creation time.